# Structure of partial infinite sumsets in the primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

In the preprint https://arxiv.org/abs/2301.10303 Tao and Ziegler prove the existence of infinite partial sumsets primes : two sequences of integers $((a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}, (b_m)_{m\in\mathbb{N}})$ such that for any given $m$, for all $n<m$ the sums $a_n+b_m$ are prime numbers.

For example, taking $a=(2,8,26)$ and $b=(3,5,11,15)$ gives a finite such sumset, if I got it right, and the paper claims the existence of infinitely long sumsets.

> 1. Is there any conjecture or guess as to how structured the two sequences can be?

For example could $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be regular, like some arithmetic or polynomial progression, or correlate very much with such progressions?

> 2. in a somewhat reverse direction, can the set of all primes  produced (all the $a_n+b_m$) be very regular?

Comment: What do you mean by "infinite partial sumsets in the primes"?

Comment: As in the paper of Tao and Ziegler. I'll add details.

Comment: I think , this is related to prime constellations. It is conjectured that each prime constellation produces infinite many prime tuples. If this is the case, the given claim would immediately follow because we can clearly construct prime constellations with an ever larger number of entries.

Comment: The restriction $n<m$ doesn't seem to apply to the example you give, Archie.

Comment: An arithmetical progression with common difference $d$ will cover all congruence classes modulo $m$ for every $m$ relatively prime to $d$, so for each $b_r>m$ one of the numbers $a_i+b_r$, $1\le i\le m$, will be a nontrivial multiple of $m$, hence, composite.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson : I think it does, you seem to be confusibg with the values of $b_m$ compared to those of $a_n$.

Comment: If the $a_i$ form an arithmetical progression with common difference $d$, and $\gcd(d,m)=1$, then for each $b_r$, one of the numbers $a_1+b_r,a_2+b_r,\dotsc,a_m+b_r$ will be zero, modulo $m$. I don't think I'm confusing anything. You asked whether the $a_i$ could form an arithmetic progression, and I'm showing they can't.

Comment: Is that OK, Archie?

Comment: Yes, this does work, thank you. My first comment only refered to my example being corect